# MySQL 8 timestamp precision in nanoseconds

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, precision, arbitrary-precision

Is it possible to store in MySQL DATETIME or other equivalent datatype with a precision of nanoseconds?

As per [fractional-seconds documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) it looks to me not possible (max 6 digit sub second precision = 1 usec) but maybe there is another datatype or function that can solve this problem?

I would like to be able to calculate difference between time ranges with precision of nanosecond and would like to avoid storing them in INT and doing my own math.

Perhaps if MySQL does not support this precision at all there is a plugin/extension I could install to get a custom DATETIME precision I could set to nanoseconds (9 digits after second comma)?

If this is not possible is there any RDBMS that supports nanosecond precision? or maybe at least NoSQL (with a function to calculate time diff in nsec precision)?

Comment: I don't know of any database that goes below microsecond precision. You're probably on your own here. Even [Postgres stops at that resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). It's worth noting Postgres allows for easy creation of custom column types.

Comment: @tadman Ad. custom column type, would it be possible to implement some math underneath the type like 1usec = 1000nsec, but 1minute = 60 sec, but 1 day = 24h and so one. I don't need to implement whole calendar but different bases. I think maximum values of diff  should not exceed days or maybe even hours and minimal nano seconds. Can custom type be composition of different bases so for nseconds after 999 value is rolled over to 000 and usecond is incremented by 1. and with minutes it goes similar way but after 59 min + 1 min the min is rolled over to 00 but hours are +1?

Comment: Just use a 64-bit value that's expressed in nanoseconds. That should do you for 292 years from some epoch.

Comment: @tadman good point! is it possible to get 64bit value that has size adjusted to its content when stored at hdd. or 64bit val will always take 64bit + overhead at disk even if only 0 or 1 is stored in it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. 64-bit values are, by definition, 8-bytes long. If you're really worrying about extra bytes maybe you need to evaluate how much data you're retaining and what storage options you have.

Comment: @tadman Your right, I need to do proper calculation of real space demand for 64bit and then I'll know if its worth to spend time on this topic. I thought that maybe they could be kind of multibyte storage like you have for UTF_8_mb4 character where a single character can take up to 4 Bytes but not always, for some of them 3 is enough. In a meantime I found out that MSSQL has 100ns accuracy for [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) datatype.

Comment: I'm not sure you can reasonably shave bytes here and get any sort of benefit. A single second expressed in nanoseconds already takes 29 bits, a year takes 54. There's absolutely zero utility in a two byte value that represents nanoseconds unless you're dealing with an extremely narrow window of time. 64-bit values take 8 bytes. Just deal with it. Looks like `datetime2` is already 9 bytes, so you're not saving anything.